# Conditionally remove parts of a snippet when the corresponding input field is left empty?

Tags: yasnippet

When writing LaTeX code I use a snippet that expands `begin` to the following

`\begin{$1}
    \label{$1:$2}
    $0
\end{$1}`

This suits most of my purposes well, since I use labels rather systematically. Still there are often times when I do not need a label in an environment and I'd love for a slightly more sophisticated snippet to be possible. I suppose my question boils down to the following:

In the above snippet, is it possible to tell yasnippet to write

`\begin{$1}
    $0
\end{$1}`

if I have started typing part of the `$0` input after leaving `$2` blank?

I realize there are many reasonable alternatives to automating this, including using either a separate, non-labelled version of this snippet when I don't need labels or replacing the second snippet line with `$2\label{$1:$3}` and killing that line when unnecessary; this is more of an educational exercise for me about the more advanced features in `yasnippets`. I feel like knowing how to optionally remove portions of a snippet based on input would be useful in other applications. Thanks in advance for your advice!